# Represent a specific address with an expression

Tags: x86, gdb

I'm using gdb and i'm trying to obtain the address represented by [es:edi] (or es:[edi]). How can i do it? The instruction is:

```
 rep movs DWORD PTR es:[edi],DWORD PTR ds:[esi]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, mainstream OSes use a flat memory model, so the DS and ES bases are both `0`.  "The address" you want is just the offset part of the full seg:off address.

To examine memory at the source, before the copy, `x  $esi`.

---

In a custom protected-mode kernel with a non-zero DS or ES base (that you're debugging via QEMU?), you'd have to manually find out the segment bases.  x86 doesn't have a simple way to query it; that part of the architectural state is not readable, only writeable (loaded from the GDT or LDT when you write a segment register with a selector).  Some people call the internal segment base/limit registers "caches", but they're not.  They're guaranteed to keep their values even if you change the GDT entry, until you manually `mov ds, eax` or whatever.

GDB doesn't really know about segmentation at all, if you want to debug code using a segmented memory model, use BOCHS's built-in debugger.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to do a Stack Buffer Overflow,i'm not very skilled in Assembly Programming yet. Since this instruction is causing me different problems i'm trying to undestand how it works.The es register is set to 0x7b, while edi has a normal address (0xbffff204). So es is not set on 0x0.

Comment: @Mr.Robot: You're not in 16-bit real mode I assume, so the value in the segment register itself is a *selector* (index into the GDT).  The actual *base* is zero if you're running under Windows, Linux, MacOS, *BSD, or any other mainstream x86 OS.  The segment base can't be read out directly in user-space, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm running under Ubuntu. The base is 0x7B. So, it's impossible to know it, right?

Comment: @Mr.Robot: No, the *selector* is 0x7B.  Since you're running under Ubuntu GNU/Linux, you definitely know for sure that the segment *base* is `0`.  i.e. that the GDT entry the kernel created, and loaded into the ES internal base/limit with `mov eax, 0x7B` / `mov es, eax`, has base = 0 and limit = 4GiB.

Comment: So, maybe i didn't understand well, the address is simple the edi content (0xbffff204), right?

Comment: @Mr.Robot: Yes.

Comment: @PeterCordes [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/x86/comments/jhf2vu/low_level_security_discord_server/) join us there we need an admin like you for the community